# Proper morphisms preserve coherent modules, non-noether case

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a proper morphism of finite presentation, and $\mathscr{F}$ a quasi-coherent $\mathscr{O}_X$-module of finite presentation.
Then for any $p$, $R^p f_* \mathscr{F}$ is finite presentation on $Y$.

If $Y$ is locally noetherian, this is standard.
But is this true for non-noetherian $Y$?

It seems that we can show it using the "passage to the limit" argument.
But I have no idea because the higher direct images in general do not commute with non-flat base change.

I tried to show it directly, imitating the proof of (III. 5. 2) of Hartshorne's AG.
But it essentially uses the hypothesis that $Y$ is locally noetherian.

(Seeing its standard proof, it seems that in order to show it, it suffices to see the following:
Let $A$ be an arbitrary ring and $\mathscr{F}$ a finitely presented module on $\mathbb{P}^n_A$.
Then $H^p(\mathbb{P}^n_A, \mathscr{F})$ is finitely presented.)

Please give me a proof, or references.

Comment: I don't have a precise reference or a proof, but have you looked in Vakil's notes? He tends to include digressions for readers interested in the non-Noetherian case, so I would suggest looking at his discussion of higher direct images.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your comment. But I could not find notes about non-noetherian case.

Comment: You are quite right. In fact I just did some digging, and this doesn't appear to even be covered in the Stacks Project, at least not directly (I didn't try to track down finite presentation of the cohomology modules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true over a non-noetherian ring $A$.

Indeed, let $X$ be a "hypersurface of degree 1" in $\mathbb{P}^n=\mbox{Proj} A[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ defined by a form $L=a_0x_0+\dots+a_nx_n$ for some $a_0,\dots,a_n\in A$. We are going to use the usual results on the cohomology of projective space, which hold with no assumption on $A$ (note that in Hartshorne they are stated with $A$ noetherian). Let $m$ be an integer which we'll choose later. Start from the exact sequence of sheaves on $P:=\mathbb{P}^n$:
$$
0\to O_P(m-1)\stackrel{L}{\to} O_P(m)\to O_X(m)\to 0.
$$
Since $H^{n-1}(P,O_P(m))=0$, the long exact sequence gives
$$
0\to H^{n-1}(X,O_X(m))\to H^n(P,O_P(m-1))\stackrel{L}{\to} H^n(P,O_P(m)).
$$
Let us now take $m=-n-1$. By Serre duality we have
\begin{align*}
& H^n(P,O_P(-n-2))\simeq H^0(P,O_P(1))^*=A^{n+1} \\
& H^n(P,O_P(-n-1))\simeq H^0(P,O_P)^*=A
\end{align*}
and the map $L$ becomes evaluation of forms $\varphi \mapsto \varphi(L)$, that is to say
$$
A^{n+1}\to A, \quad (r_0,\dots,r_n)\mapsto r_0a_0+\dots+r_na_n.
$$
Thus we have identified $H^{n-1}(X,O_X(-n-1))$ with the kernel of this map. But this is pathological: for some (especially non-coherent) rings $A$, finite generation may fail. For an example with say $n=1$ for simplicity of writing, one can take
$$
A=\frac{k[a_0,a_1,u_i,v_i,i\ge 0]}{(u_ia_0+v_ia_1)_{i\ge 0}}.
$$
In such a ring the finitely generated ideal $I=(a_0,a_1)$ is not finitely presented, which causes the trouble. Here $H^0(X,O_X(-2))$ is the submodule of $A^2$ generated by all pairs $(u_i,v_i)$ and is not finitely generated.

In most situations where one wants to use cohomology to prove a certain statement which is stable by base change, this is not a problem, however. Indeed, under suitable finite presentation assumptions as in your question, one can argue that the data of the situation defined over $A$ come by base change from data defined over a noetherian ring $A_0$, then use finiteness of cohomology to obtain the desired statement over $A_0$, then base change to obtain the statement over $A$.